# T-SQL. Порядок проверки условий, соединенных оператором OR

Tags: sql-server

В таких языках программирования, как c# или с++, если первый операнд оператора || является истиной (true), то последующая проверка не выполняется.

А как на счет T-SQL?

Мне нужно выбрать только одну запись, причем порядок выполнения условий важен – если первое условие не выполняется, то нужно проверить второе и только затем третье. Будет ли подобный запрос верным?

```
Select TOP 1 * From Table WHERE 
  <условие с приоритетом 1>
OR 
  <условие с приоритетом 2>
OR
  <условие с приоритетом 3>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я тут немного погуглил и возникло следующее решение:

```
Select TOP 1 * FROM (
  Select *
  , CASE 
    WHEN <условие 1> then 1 
    WHEN <условие 2> THEN 2
    WHEN <условие 3> THEN 3
  ELSE 4
  END as Prio
  FROM  Table
) T1 
WHERE Prio <> 4
ORDER BY Prio asc
```

Всем спасибо, вопрос закрыт.

Comment: Вы могли case написать непосредственно в order by и тогда бы делать подзапрос не пришлось

Answer (score 1):

Анализатор запросов смотрит на все условия, перечисленные в WHERE, соответственно при выборке данных все условия будут приняты во внимание.

Чтобы получить нужное вам поведение, нужно писать составной запрос.

Answer (score 0):

И еще один ответ, основанный на подсказке от Mike - это использование CASE в ORDER BY.

```
Select TOP (1) *
  FROM Table
Order By 
  (CASE WHEN <условие 1> THEN 1 ELSE 2 END), 
  (CASE WHEN <условие 2> THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
  (CASE WHEN <условие 3> THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
```

Этот вариант должен работать без ограничений. Но есть проблема: если ни одно из условий не подходит вернется неверное значение. Поэтому здесь нужно еще добавлять WHERE со всеми условиями